# finding the longest common prefix of elements inside a list

Tags: python

I have a sequence `print(lcp(["flower","flow","flight", "dog"]))` which should return *fl*. Currently I can get it to return *flowfl*.

I can locate the instances where *o* or *w* should be removed, and tried different approaches to remove them. However they seem to hit syntax issue, which I cannot seem to resolve by myself.

I would very much appreciate a little guidance to either have the tools to remedy this issue my self, or learn from a working proposed solution.

```
def lcp(strs):
    if not isinstance(strs, list) or len(strs) == 0:
        return ""

    if len(strs) == 1:
        return strs[0]

    original = strs[0]
    original_max = len(original)
    result = ""

    for _, word in enumerate(strs[1:],1):
        current_max = len(word)
        i = 0
        while i < current_max and i < original_max:
            copy = "".join(result)
            if len(copy) and copy[i-1] not in word:
#                 result = result.replace(copy[i-1], "")
#                 result = copy[:i-1]
                    print(copy[i-1], copy, result.index(copy[i-1]), i, word)
            if word[i] == original[i]:
                result += word[i]
            i += 1

    return result
        
print(lcp(["flower","flow","flight", "dog"])) # returns flowfl should be fl
print(lcp(["dog","car"])) # works
print(lcp(["dog","racecar","car"])) # works
print(lcp([])) # works
print(lcp(["one"])) # works
```

I worked on an alternative which does not be solve removing inside the same loop, adding a counter at the end. However my instincts suggest it can be solved within the for and while loops without increasing code bloat.

```
    if len(result) > 1:
        counter = {char: result.count(char) for char in result}
        print(counter)
```

Comment: Why should `lcp(["flower","flow","flight", "dog"])` return `fl`? `dog` doesn't begin with `fl`, so shouldn't that actually return an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returns the longest prefix that the set of words have in common.

```py
def lcp(strs):
    if len(strs) == 0:
        return ""
    
    result = strs[0]

    for word in strs[1:]:
        for i, (l1, l2) in enumerate(zip(result, word)):
            if l1 != l2:
                result = result[:i]
                break
        else:
            result = result[:i+1]

    return result
```

Results:

```py
>>> print(lcp(["flower","flow","flight"]))
fl
>>> print(lcp(["flower","flow","flight", "dog"]))

>>> print(lcp(["dog","car"]))

>>> print(lcp(["dog","racecar","car"]))

>>> print(lcp([]))

>>> print(lcp(["one"]))
one
>>> print(lcp(["one", "one"]))
one
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the solution, I will study it to improve my productivity.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this using the below approach.

```
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
        N = len(strs)
        if N == 1:
            return strs[0]
        len_of_small_str, small_str = self.get_min_str(strs)
        ans = ""
        for i in range(len_of_small_str):
            ch = small_str[i]
            is_qualified = True
            for j in range(N):
                if strs[j][i] != ch:
                    is_qualified = False
                    break
            if is_qualified:
                ans += ch
            else:
                break
        return ans
        
    def get_min_str(self, A):
        min_len = len(A[0])
        s = A[0]
        for i in range(1, len(A)):
            if len(A[i]) < min_len:
                min_len = len(A[i])
                s = A[i]
                
        return min_len, s
```

Comment: Why use a class here ? And you need a test to handle empty strs list (the code is currently crashing if `strs = []`).

Comment: I have written this code in leetcode and passes all test cases.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to rephrase your goal.

By your description you don't want the longest common prefix, but the prefix that the most words have in common with the first one.

One of your issues is that your tests only test one real case and four edgecases. Make some more real examples.

Here's my proposition: I mostly added the elif to check if we already have a difference on the first letter to then discard the entry.

It also overwrites the original to rebuild the string based on the common prefix with the next word (if there are any)

```py
def lcp(strs):
    if not isinstance(strs, list) or len(strs) == 0:
        return ""

    if len(strs) == 1:
        return strs[0]

    original = strs[0]
    result = ""

    for word in strs[1:]:
        i = 0
        while i < len(word) and i < len(original) :
            if word[i] == original[i]:
                result += word[i]
            elif i == 0:
                result = original
                break
            i += 1
        
        original = result
        result = ""

    return original
        
print(lcp(["flower","flow","flight", "dog"])) # fl
print(lcp(["shift", "shill", "hunter", "shame"])) # sh
print(lcp(["dog","car"])) # dog
print(lcp(["dog","racecar","car"])) # dog
print(lcp(["dog","racecar","dodge"])) # do
print(lcp([])) # [nothing]
print(lcp(["one"])) # one
```